# NSButton change width

Tags: macos, swift, width, nsbutton

I have a button with a title and image. The title of the button change dependent on the selected language. So i want that the button has always the width of the title plus image. I thought it was something easy like this:

```
var size = selectMenuItemButton.attributedTitle.size
myButton.bounds.size.width = size.width + 10.0
```

But the width of the button stay the same. What i'm doing wrong?

Edit: 
Also try

```
myButton.frame.size.width = size.width + 10.0
```

And

```
myButton.sizeToFit()
```

Didn't work neither

Edit2:
I have created a clear project with two buttons. If the one button is clicked the title of the another button is changed. The outcome is the same, i want that the width is change too, but i can't achieve that

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(test.attributedTitle.size.width)
    myButton.title = "blublublublub"
    var size = test.attributedTitle.size
    myButton.frame.size.width = size.width
    println(test.attributedTitle.size.width)
}
```

Comment: What is `myButton.frame.size.width` before and after? could you print it?

Comment: If i set frame.size.width and make print before and after i can see that the frame width is bigger. But the button is still the same size. It's equal if i set the width to 10 or 50 the outcome is always the same.

Comment: have you added this button to the main view as a subview? where is the rest of the code?

Comment: No it's not in a subview or something. I have created now a new clear project, where i change the title in the runtime and the outcome is the same. If the title is to long the break is always on the same character. The only thing i can archive is that the font is getting bigger or smaller

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough.. you should make it easier for others to help you by including all the code you are using

Comment: I have added all code from the new project, but i don't think there is an additional information there.

Comment: Also I would recommend for the sender to be type UIButton if the button is the sender. That way you can have easy reference to that button. Also to change the title use setTitleForState or else the title will not set. Same goes for image, use setImageForState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have the answer, i needed just set title again after i set the size:

```
myButton.title = "blublublublub"
var size = myButton.attributedTitle.size
myButton.frame.size.width = size.width
myButton.title = "blublublublub"
```

If someone want to change the size outside @IBAction you need to use dispatch:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.myButton.title = "blublublublub"
        var size = self.myButton.attributedTitle.size
        self.myButton.frame.size.width = size.width
        self.myButton.title = "blublublublub"
    }
```